# Demagnetising $H$ field

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetostatics, ferromagnetism

If we have a permanent magnet we know that we have a $H$ field opposite in direction to the residual magnetic field $B_r$. The $H$ field causes a demagnetisation, but how does it do it? We know that the physical field (the field which causes the Lorentz force) is the magnetic field $B$.

Answer (score 0):

The H field is caused by the positive and negative poles that develop at the end of the magnet in the opposite direction of the B field. Whether H or B is the *real* field is somewhat a matter of taste, for neither is directly measurable in any easy way and both are the result of averaging; some even say that within the matter they are both just mathematical fictions. There is one well-known and often referenced experiment by Rassetti: ‘‘Deflections of mesons in magnetized iron,’’ Phys. Rev. 66, 1–5 1944, (note the date!) that claims to verify that the Lorentz force formula does indeed have B in it and not H. Here is a quote from Brown: Magnetostatic Principles in Ferromagnetism

> The safest view to adopt regarding the field vectors Band H, as they have been defined at internal points, is that they have definite mathematical meanings in terms of a given magnetization distribution, but that no physical meaning should be attributed to them. Physical interpretations are possible in special cases; for instance, in the case of a homogeneous isotropic toroidal specimen, with a toroidal magnetizing winding, the field vector H is identical with the flux density of the winding alone; but introduction of a gap, or of inhomogeneity or anisotropy, immediately destroys this identity. When physical interpretations are possible, they should be based on direct demonstrations in the relevant specific
>   cases.

Comment: That’s ok. The $ H  $ in some special cases can be interpreted physically, but anyway the question remains. I agree with the fact that there’s this demagnetising $H$ field, but then? How does this field influence the magnetisation of the material? That is to say, why does $H$ causes demagnetisation with time?

Comment: There is a B=B(H) monotonic relationship for every material, if H is smaller because of demagnetization, then so is B. ("Relationship" and not a "function" necessarily, see ferromagnetic hysteresis)

Comment: Suppose we have an indefinite ferromagnet. If we turn on the $H$ field such that we reach the saturation, and then we turn it off, we obtain a magnet with a residual magnetisation $M_r$ and a residual magnetic field $B_r$ (hysteresis curve). Because it’s indefinite there is no $H$ field inside, right? If now we take the same ferromagnet with finite dimensions and we magnetise it as before, we obtain the same residual magnetic field $B_r$ plus a magnetic field $B_d$ (opposite to $B_r$) caused by the demagnetising $H$ field. So with finite dimensions we have $B’<B_r$. Am I right?

Comment: What is an "indefinite" ferromagnet? I have not heard that term.

Comment: I’m sorry, I meant “infinitely long”

Comment: I see. So you assume that there is no demagnetizing field as in the case of a toroid (you would also need an infinitely long winding to go with an infinitely long ferromagnet, I think for your example a toroid would do just as well). I think  you misunderstand what B=B(H) means. The B=B(H) relationship is supposed to be a *material* relationship independent of the actual configuration of the specimen. This is why one must account for the demagnetizing field in an actual measurement because the "external" and "demagnetizing" fields together will give the actual internal H.

Comment: When considered this way B=B(H) is a material relationship independent of the geometry so the residual magnetization are the same in both cases.